# Android Twilio Video - get camera stream

Tags: android, video, android-camera, twilio, twilio-api

I am currently developing an app using the Twilio Video API: https://www.twilio.com/video
It is still in Beta, but works great for the most part. And maybe there is also a way to solve my issue.

For my app I need to switch the camera and to turn on the light of the back camera. The first one is easily done with Twilio, but for the second one I do not have the camera object to control the camera light. Is there any way to get the camera object? Or can I create the camera object myself and then pass it to Twilio? Or is there another approach to turn on the light?

My code for the camera preview. As in the examples I use the `CameraCapturer` to get the camera preview into a view:

```
cameraCapturer = CameraCapturer.create(MyActivity.this, CameraCapturer.CameraSource.CAMERA_SOURCE_FRONT_CAMERA, capturerErrorListener());
startPreview();
```

and the preview:

```
private void startPreview() {
    if (cameraCapturer != null) {
        cameraCapturer.startPreview(previewFrameLayout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now an official sample from Twilio over on their Github page: [exampleAdvancedCameraCapturer](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/tree/master/exampleAdvancedCameraCapturer)

You can see how the toggle works in [AdvancedCameraCapturerActivity.java](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/blob/master/exampleAdvancedCameraCapturer/src/main/java/com/twilio/video/examples/advancedcameracapturer/AdvancedCameraCapturerActivity.java)

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here. You are right, and the current version of the SDK does not allow for you to control the Camera Capturer as you could if you just created the camera object yourself.

We are aware of this though, and are working on a new version where you will be able to do just that.

For the time being I would suggest trying to still create your own camera object manually just so you can turn on the backlight, and I think that as long as you don't call preview on it, you shouldn't end up with a conflict.

I would imagine something like this (untested) would work.

```
private void turnOnFlash() {
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    camera.setParameters(params);
}
```

Also add this to your AndroidManifest.

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

And then  you would call that method where you call startPreview().

This solutions should get you going for the time being, but you will be able to pass your own camera object in the future, so if that's not a pressing functionality for the time being, I would then wait for the updated version.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you, this works when called before starting the CameraCapturer. Sadly, in my scenario I have to toggle the light on and off during the video call (toggle command via websocket connection). Pausing and restarting the preview would be okay, but right now the CameraCapturer keeps the camera on pause and I get an `java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service` when getting the camera myself

Comment: @Marcos Placona any update on this? Is it now possible to turn the flashlight on while on WebRTC stream?

Comment: @EnricoCasini Aaron from Twilio was awesome enough to create a new sample for exactly this use case. You can see it on their Github: https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/tree/master/exampleAdvancedCameraCapturer

Comment: Hi Placona, as asked by Casini, is it possible to turn on a flashlight in the ongoing video. If we implement that flashlight would turn on but the camera instance changed.

Comment: Have you seen the example above by Aaron?

Answer (score 0):

You should create this one:

```
private boolean flashOn = false;

private final CameraParameterUpdater flashToggler = new CameraParameterUpdater() {
    @Override public void apply(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        if (parameters.getFlashMode() != null) {
            String flashMode = flashOn ?
                    Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF :
                    Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH;
            parameters.setFlashMode(flashMode);
            flashOn = !flashOn;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(*context*,
                    R.string.flash_not_supported,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Set this and the func below in a class where you have an access to the CameraCapturerCompat (name from a Twilio example) object

```
public void setFlashOn(boolean state) {
    flashOn = !state;

    cameraCapturerCompat.updateCameraParameters(flashToggler);
}
```

and then on your CameraCapturerCompat class:

```
public void updateCameraParameters(CameraParameterUpdater flashToggler) {
    if (usingCamera1()) { 
        camera1Capturer.updateCameraParameters(flashToggler);
    }
}
```